# Apache Flex SDK и Adobe Flex SDK - это одно и тоже?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

В чем отличие Apache Flex SDK от Adobe Flex SDK ?
Вот как мне ответили на подобный вопрос -
**"Это компилятор(AIR SDK), а не платформа рантайма."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Flex SDK - это полностью перешедшая в руки opensource сообщества версия Adobe Flex SDK. На данный момент особо сильных различий нет. 
Апач версия активно апдейтится и развивается.

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо! А Вы не подскажите, что в таком случаи лучше использовать, AIR SDK с ASC 2.0 или Apache Flex SDK ? И ещё очень прошу, если можно и если Вы знаете, расскажите, как установить Apache Flex SDK на FD.

Comment: - использую AIR SDK, на апач пока переходить не вижу смысла
- в настройках fd добавить папку с сдк - Settings -> AS3Context -> Installed Flex SDKs -> Добавить(Add)

Comment: У меня сегодня "день невезения"... С апач выдаёт ошибку - дException: Could not locate lib\fcsh.jar in Flex SDK. С AIR SDK, тоже проблемы, скомпилировать могу, а раскомпилировать нет. Скорее всего не могу раскомпилировать из-за того, что тоже где то не так настроено.

Comment: Раскомпилировать? 

Зачем вам апач флекс?

В fd встроенный (сам качает) Flex (4.6) и AIR SDK (3.9), используйте их, они бесплатные и открытые.

Comment: Неее, Вы не правильно поняли :) Раскомпилировать собственную swf, чтобы убедиться что inline работает. Когда использую AIR SDK (3.9) идущую с последней версией FD, то декомпилятор ошибку выдает и я прихожу к мнению, что что то не правильно.

Comment: может декомпилятор просто не понимает свежую версию swf

и вообще inline это последний способ поднять производительность, например когда счет идет на единицы миллисекунд, и исчерпаны все возможности архитектуры приложения

Comment: inline - для меня это, быстрая - самописная математика. И много мелких собственных мелочей. А по поводу не понимает... Вот когда в настройках стоит Flex (4.6) + AIR SDK (3.9), то декомпилируется нормально, но мне сказали, что нужно просто AIR SDK (3.9) вставить. И не ломает уже..  а ломатель Sothink  последняя версия.....Пишу в блоке темы.

Comment: не понимаю, айр это тип приложений, которые создаются на основе swf файла, куда там еще айр сдк можно вставить?